# How to print value with assert in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to print value with assert function in python.

Below is example code:

```
HEADERS_VALID = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'fiware-Service': 'test', 'fiware-ServicePath': '/t1'}
HEADERS_INVALID = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'fiwareService': 'test', 'fiwareServicePath': '/t1'}

def test_for_valid_headers(notification):
    notification['data'][0] = {
        'id': 'Room0',
        'type': 'Room',
        'temperature': {'type': 'Number', 'value': '100', 'metadata': {'dateModified': {'type': 'DateTime','value': '1980-01-30T00:00:00.000+00:00'}}},
        'pressure': {'type': 'Number', 'value': '10', 'metadata': {'dateModified': {'type': 'DateTime','value': '1980-01-30T00:00:00.000+00:00'}}},
    }

    res_post = requests.post(data=json.dumps(notification),
                      headers=HEADERS_VALID)
    time.sleep(1)
    assert res_post.status_code == 200
    assert res_post.json() == 'Notification successfully processed'

    get_url = "{}/entities/Room0".format(QL_URL)
    res_get = requests.get(get_url, headers=HEADERS_VALID)

    assert res_get.status_code == 200

    exp_values = {
        "attributes": [{'attrName': 'pressure', 'values': [10.0]}, {'attrName': 
       'temperature', 'values': [100.0]}],
        "entityId": 'Room0',
        "index": [
            '1980-01-30T00:00:00.000+00:00'
        ]
    }
    assert res_get.json() == exp_values
```

Here in `res_post.json()` the actual response is  `"Notification successfully processed for : 'tenant' test, 'fiwareServicePath' /t1, 'entity_id' ['Room0']"` which is not equal to `'Notification successfully processed'`  in `assert` function. So, want to add rest part in assert fucntion.

After this response i added ,

```
assert res_post.json() == "Notification successfully processed for: : 'tenant' %s, 'fiwareServicePath' %s" %(fiware_s, fiware_sp)
```

which is giving error as : `NameError: name 'fiware' is not defined`
I am not able to get what i am doing wrong in this statement.Any help on this will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error doesn't look like it fits with the assertion statement shown... is there more code that we're missing?

Comment: `fiware` (and `fiware_s`/`fiware_sp`) do not seem to be defined at the assertion statement.

Comment: @EdWard, I have added code but while debugging code it is throwing error in "assert res_post.json() "  as below:

`assert "Notification...fiware-ServicePath" == 'Notification ...lly processed'`
`E         - Notification successfully processed for : 'tenant' test, 'fiwareServicePath' /t1`

`E         + Notification successfully processed`
`

Comment: seems that you missed `fiware` variable.one alternative to your assert `assert  "Notification successfully processed for" in res_post.json() ` or use `assertIn`